# RestTemplate Call with No Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have set proxy in my environment variables , however for a specific call made via RestTemplate , I shouldn't be using any proxy. Is there a way to disable proxy for a specific resttemplate call?

Comment: Shame this is closed: the following should work  SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setProxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY); new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

Comment: Proxy.NO_PROXY comes from java.net. If you don't specify a proxy you get the default from environment variables, provided by URL.openConnection() (not Spring), but you can specify a Proxy that bypasses the proxy and Spring will pass this through to openConnection()

Comment: I would argue this question is "clear and concise" it comes up first in google and duck duck go indicating search engines agree with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of disabling and re-enabling the proxy, I'd use separate RestTemplates:

```java
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean(name="proxyRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate proxyRestTemplate() {
        // return a RestTemplate with proxy settings
    }


    @Bean(name="nonProxyRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate nonProxyRestTemplate() {
        // return a RestTemplate without proxy settings
    }
}
```

And in your classes:

```java
@Component
public class SomeClassWithProxy {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public SomeClass(@Qualifier("proxyRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SomeClassWithoutProxy {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public SomeClass(@Qualifier("nonProxyRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michiel , here both proxy and no. Proxy seem to have same code. How is it possible to disable proxy in no proxy bean?

Comment: Would you be able to add some relevant code snippets to your original post to show us how the proxy is set up? It might help me in understanding how you've configured your RestTemplate.